# Questions regarding proof of Minkowski's Integral Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I have several questions regarding the proof of the following theorem:

[image]

a. The proof states that 1 follows from 2. But I don't understand why we're allowed to treat $f^y(x)$ as $f(x,y)$. Is it because the latter's appearance in no. 1 (under the integral over $X$) is the same as holding $y$ constant? How can I think about this more clearly to avoid confusion of when these are equal?

b. The proof of 2 uses Riesz's Representation with the following transition (where $g\geq 0$ and $g \in L^q$):

$$\sup_{g\neq 0 \\ ||g||_q=1} \Bigg|\int_Xg\int_Yf^y(x)d\nu d\mu\Bigg| = \sup_{g\neq 0 \\ ||g||_q=1} \Bigg|\int_Y\int_X gf^y(x)d\nu d\mu\Bigg|$$

using Tonelli. But I cannot see why $g(x)f^y(x)$ is measurable, and again why I can treat $f^y(x)$ as I wish (once a function of $y$ and once of $x$ -- why is this allowed?). Even if $g(x)f^y(x)=g(x)f(x,y)$ then what makes the latter measurable (which is one of the requirements for applying Tonelli. The non-negativity requirement is clear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complaint about the assertion 2 is absolutely correct: In fact, it is not even clear why the vector integral $h(x)$ should exist, in general. From what you cite the proof seems to omit the delicate measurability question.

This measurability question **can** be solved, but it requires a lot of work. More precisely, it can be shown for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces: If $f$ is measurable on the product space, then $y\mapsto f^y$ is measurable as a function into $L^p$ (if $p<\infty$). Conversely, if $y\mapsto f^y$ is measurable as a function into $L^p$ then there *do exist* representation of $f^y$ such that $f$ is measurable on the product.

Both assertions are non-trivial to show (and the first assertion is false in case $p=\infty$ as can be seen for $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $x<y$,}\\0&\text{if $x\ge y$.}\end{cases}$$

They are shown in a more general context in Section 4.4 in my monograph [Ideal Spaces (Springer, Berlin 1997](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540631606) (though the $L_p$ case is already covered in Hille-Phillips monograph on semigroups).

Fortunately, concerning the proof of assertion 1, you do not need any of this: You can just use the part of the proof which you cited (with $f(\cdot,y)$ instead of $f^y$, so you will not run into measurability problems), making use of the dual characterization

$$\lVert F\rVert_p=\sup_{\lVert g\rVert_q=1}\int Fg\text.$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $f$ is real valued. $f^y(x) = f(x, y)$ is the definition of $f^y : X \to \mathbb{R}$. It's also written as $f^y = f(\cdot, y)$. The way I would write (1) is that if $f : X \times Y \to [0, \infty]$ is $M \otimes N$ - $B([0, \infty])$ measurable and $p \in [1, \infty)$, then
$$\left\|\int_{Y}f(\cdot, y)\,d\nu(y)\right\|_{L^p(X, \mu)} \leq \int_{Y}\|f(\cdot, y)\|_{L^p(X, \mu)}\,d\nu(y).$$
We need $p < \infty$ so that we can use Tonelli's theorem to get measurability of all functions being integrated. I would say that (2) follows from (1) by replacing $f$ with $|f|$.

It is easy to prove that $(x, y) \mapsto g(x)f(x, y)$ is $M \otimes N$ - $B(\mathbb{R})$ measurable: Note that $(x, y) \mapsto x \mapsto g(x)$ is measurable (being a composition of measurable functions) and $(x, y) \mapsto f(x, y)$ is measurable by assumption. Thus their product $(x, y) \mapsto g(x)f(x, y)$ is measurable